# If $p$, $q$, $r$ and $s$ are four sides of a quadrilateral, then find the minimum value of $\frac{p^2+ q^2 + r^2}{s^2}$ with logic

Tags: geometry, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, geometric-inequalities

If $p$, $q$, $r$ and $s$ are four sides of a quadrilateral then find the minimum value of $\frac{p^2+ q^2 + r^2}{s^2}$ with logic.

Please help me with this.

Comment: We will definitely help if you show us what have you tried.

Comment: also, it is not well defined: consider the rectangle with sides $(1,2,1,2) = (2,1,2,1)$, but $\frac{1^2+2^2+1^2}{2^2} = \frac{3}{2} \neq 9 = \frac{2^2+1^2+2^2}{1^2}$

Comment: My sir gave me this question.

Comment: so is it implicit that $s$ is the longest side?

Comment: I used A.M and G.M, went close but could not do.

Comment: My logic says there is no minimum at all. The infimum is $1\over3$, but you can't reach it.

Answer (score 1):

By the triangle inequality and by C-S we obtain:
$$\frac{p^2+q^2+r^2}{s^2}>\frac{p^2+q^2+r^2}{(p+q+r)^2}=\frac{(1+1+1)(p^2+q^2+r^2)}{3(p+q+r)^2}\geq\frac{(p+q+r)^2}{3(p+q+r)^2}=\frac{1}{3}.$$
The equality does not occur, but easy to see that $\frac{1}{3}$ is an infimum.